# How can I use an environment variable in the MySQL console

Tags: mysql

I can connect to the console as root using an environment variable:

```
mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

I’d like to be able to use a different environment variable in a statement

```
CREATE USER ${MYSQL_USER} IDENTIFIED BY ${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD};
```

Which obviously doesn’t work (or why would I be asking).  Is there any way I can use an environment variable in the console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to access environment variables from MySQL queries. But you can construct the MySQL query and substitute variables in the shell.

```
mysql -e "CREATE USER '{$MYSQL_USER}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD}'"
```

The shell will substitute the variables into the string before it's passed to the `mysql` command. For longer queries you can use a here-doc:

```
mysql <<EOF
CREATE USER '{$MYSQL_USER}' 
IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD}'
EOF
```

Comment: I ended up passing the environment variables into my docker container and used a method similar to yours.  Thanks!